# Git is not prompting me for password

Tags: git, github

When pushing, even if it's a private repository, Git bash is not prompting me for Github password. A couple of years ago I set up Git in my computer. I set up the username and email, but I do not remember setting up any password at all.

- I'd like to know why is this happening. Does this mean that anyone can just push into my private repos?
- Can I check somehow if any password has been stored somewhere in my computer? I'd like to know that to make sure it's not stored in a plain text file.

Comment: You might have set up SSH keys?

Comment: It doesn't seem so. When I run `ls -al ~/.ssh` in my local repo folder, bash it says there is not such a file or directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this problem comes on a Windows machine, do the following.

Go to Credential Manager

Go to Windows Credentials

Delete the entries under Generic Credentials

Try connecting again. This time, it should prompt you for the correct username and password.

Comment: That's it! I can see there that the password is shown as stored, I'll just remove the entries. Thank you.